# How to produce random integer numbers from 0 - 100 but by 10s only?

Tags: r, random

Using R (maybe `runif()` or `sample()`? ), how can one produce a set of integer random values? Lets say 100 random values from 0 - 100, but the values should only be by 10s (e.g 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)

Comment: produce 0...10 and multiply by 10

Answer (score 4):

`sample` will allow you to do the sampling easily. If we create a vector of the values we want it should be easy enough.  `seq(0,100,by=10)` will allow us to construct a sequence starting at 0, ending at 100, by 10.

```
sample(seq(0,100,by=10), 100, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

One could select numbers uniformly from 0...10 and then multiply by 10. Sample code:

```
q <- 10*sample(seq(0,10), 1000, replace=TRUE)
```